# Jquery loop on two array in JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, json, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and when I return two array in JSON to a jQuery code, I can't loop on it, I'm always having "undefined" but no error: here is my jQuery code:

```
$(".select-zone").change(function() {

    var select = $(".select-lieu");
    var value = $(this).val();

    select.empty().append("<option value='-1'>Lieu / Salle</option>");
    if (value != -1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('admin_default_getlieusallebyzone', {
                id: value
            }),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                $.each(data[i], function(val1) {
                    var id = val1.id;
                    var libelle = val1.nom;
                    var numero = val1.numero;
                    if (numero != undefined) {
                        select.append("<option value=" + id + ">" + libelle + " - " + numero + "</option>");
                    } else {
                        select.append("<option value=" + id + ">" + libelle + " </option>");
                    }

                });

                $.each(data[i], function(val2) {
                    var id = val2.id;
                    var libelle = val2.nom;
                    var numero = val2.numero;
                    if (numero != undefined) {
                        select.append("<option value=" + id + ">" + libelle + " - " + numero + "</option>");
                    } else {
                        select.append("<option value=" + id + ">" + libelle + " </option>");
                    }

                });
                select.prop('disabled', false);
            })
        });
    }
});
```

How I can resolve this ?

Comment: what exactly do you return from your controller under the route `admin_default_getlieusallebyzone` ? Could you paste the output?

Comment: Can you paste your json response?

Comment: My json response is: http://puu.sh/nvJSO/8ef376f8e3.png and the seconde array: http://puu.sh/nvJUx/396d4a9fbb.png

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `$.ajax()` seems a bit invalid, as you have to have `data:{}` to send values to the respective url and `dataType` should have to be in the options for `$.ajax()`.

Change to this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: Routing.generate('admin_default_getlieusallebyzone', 
    data:{
        id: value
    },
    dataType: 'json'
 })
```